# Linux terminal tail commands

Tags: linux, terminal, command, tail

i've searched a lot for this and i couldn't find any helpful information, what's the difference between "**tail –f /var/log/messages**" and "**tail –f /var/log/maillog**" in Linux?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A brief list:

```
/var/log/messages : General message and system related stuff
/var/log/auth.log : Authenication logs
/var/log/kern.log : Kernel logs
/var/log/cron.log : Crond logs (cron job)
/var/log/maillog : Mail server logs
/var/log/boot.log : System boot log
/var/log/mysqld.log : MySQL database server log file
/var/log/secure or /var/log/auth.log : Authentication log
/var/log/utmp or /var/log/wtmp : Login records file
```